# Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' even though this field is nowhere in table or query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following insert:

```
insert into li_appointments.li_appointments
    (`app_datetime`, `app_facility`, 
    `app_department`, `app_address`, 
    `app_language`, `app_requesting_person`, 
    `app_service_provider`, `app_client_id`, 
    `app_client_other`, `app_medicaid_status`, 
    `les_name`, `les_dob`, `les_medicaid_id`, 
    `app_notes`, `created_by`, `created_on`,
    `app_callback_num`, `uofu_csn` ) 
Values(cast(concat(str_to_date('02/28/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
    , ' ', '09:45') as datetime), 'testt', 'test', 'test'
    , 'test' , 'test' , 'test', '1094', 'test', '1'
    , AES_ENCRYPT('****', 'test'), '10/10/1000', AES_ENCRYPT('****', 'test')
    , 'test', 'admin', now(), 'testtest', '')
```

And I get this error every time:

```
Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
```

Even though there is no column 'id' anywhere.  This query worked perfectly yesterday so I am at a loss.

This is the table we are trying to edit:

```
CREATE TABLE `li_appointments` (
  `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_facility` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_department` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_language` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_requesting_person` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_service_provider` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_client_other` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_medicaid_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_health_program` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `les_name` varbinary(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `les_dob` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `les_medicaid_id` varbinary(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_total_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_workorder_received` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_admin_fee` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `wo_entered_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_callback_num` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `terp_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_covered_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `covered_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uofu_csn` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`),
  KEY `created_By` (`created_by`),
  KEY `index2` (`app_id`,`app_datetime`,`terp_id`,`app_language`),
  KEY `Extra` (`app_id`,`app_datetime`,`app_client_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=515394839 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: have you committed any changes to your code after it worked?

Comment: what does SHOW CREATE TABLE li_appointments look like ?

Comment: @Sirac we changed the user who is executing the query. That is all.

Comment: maybe your insert-statement is connected to a trigger which fails and generates this error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this query, you are missing something else: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2b2b/1/0

Comment: @Sirac  You are a genius.  Someone added a trigger unknown to me that was failing!

Comment: glad i could help, may i ask what that trigger was about?

Comment: @Sirac, that's indeed a good catch.

Comment: i had a similar problem too, it took me some time to figure it out, but you learn with every failure and it's good to see that this knowlegde can help you or others.